# url rewriting in php htaccess

Tags: php

Hai
 I have 2 questions.

1) I want to create a clean url web site. My server is CGI/FastCGI. I know how this does in apache. But how I will do this in CGI server, does any one give me the details?

2) I want to create the clean url like 
`mydomain/index.php?id=1&sort=a` to

`mydomain/index/id/1/sort/a`
 Is it possible?

Does any one help me?

Comment: CGI/FastCGI is not the name of web-server. it's just a technology. You have to nave the server software to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

CGI is not a server. Apache, IIS are examples of web servers.

If you are using Apache (this is incredibly likely if using fastCGI), then using this in your `.htaccess` file will redirect requests from `mydomain/index/id/1/sort/a` to `mydomain/index.php?id=1&sort=a` in the background, without the user knowing:

```
RewriteRule ^index/id/([0-9]+)/sort/(a|d)$ /index.php?id=$1&sort=$2 [NC]
```

Hopefully this is self explanatory.

`.htaccess` is a feature of apache, for which you may need to enable [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#allowoverride) in httpd.conf